# Disable the edge sidebar using Capabilities and EdgeOptions

Tags: testing, automation, microsoft-edge, automation-testing, desiredcapabilities

**All I want to know how I can disable edge sidebar using Edge capability.
so i can use it in automation.
I am aware about two different ways to it mentioned below.**

1. Using .send_keys Shift + Ctrl + /
2. From registry Editor
   Open Registry Editor by typing regedit in the Run prompt and pressing the Enter key.
   Navigate to the following path:
   Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Edge
   Right-click on the right section, and choose to create a DWORD with the name as HubsSidebarEnabled
   Set the value as 0x00000000 to disable it.

**But i want to do it using Capabilities and EdgeOptions..**

[Attaching image of sidebar in edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05Emo.png)

Please mention if any solution on this...

Edge version -  Version 107.0.1418.62 (Official build)  (64-bit)
OS - win10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### EdgeOptions, Capabilities

##### Solution on C#

```
var options = new EdgeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--disable-features=msHubApps");
```

##### Solution on Ruby

```
DESIRED_CAPABILITIES = {    
    edge: { 
        browser_opts: {args:    %w( --disable-features=msHubApps),}
    }
}

Resource - https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/EdgeWebDriver/issues/61
```

Comment: does not work anymore as of version 114

Answer (score 1):

I searched a lot including some official documents: [Capabilities and EdgeOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/capabilities-edge-options), [Browser Options](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/options/), [Capabilities](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#capabilities), but didn't find such Capabilities/EdgeOptions.

I think we can't disable Edge sidebar using Edge capability for now. I suggest that you can [provide feedback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/contact) to Edge WebDriver team to help improve the product. Thanks for your understading.

Answer (score 0):

I'll also add that another possibility would be to disable it with prefs.

**Java :**

```
Map<String, Object> lPrefs = new HashMap<>();

// Disable Hub Apps Tower
lPrefs.put("browser.show_hub_apps_tower", false);

edgeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", lPrefs);
```

I find it pretty easy to do like that as I also edit a bunch of other features putting them in my HashMap.

You can find all available preferences using [edge://prefs-internals/](https://edge://prefs-internals/). Tinkering with this can be very powerful as you can basically find anything that you would need.

Comment: @pgundlupet As far as I know this specific options might not be working anymore. I managed to find the name of the option by following this procedure : (1) Open edge://prefs-internals/ (2) Copy and paste it somewhere (I'd suggest Notepad++) (3) Search and change the option that you wish to know the name using Edge user interface. (4) Go back to edge://prefs-internals/ copy and paste it somewhere and now you can compare both files (Notepad++ has a plugin that can automatically do that). Search for all differences and find the right one

Answer (score 0):

@Matteo That didn't work and I could still see the Sidebar.

```
caps = { options: { prefs: { show_hub_apps_tower: false } } }
```

I am working on Watir with Ruby on Edge v114

Comment: "show_hub_apps_tower": false and "browser.show_hub_apps_tower": false does not work anymore